# Flutter web renderer (not CanvasKit): Nested Y Axis rotation causes a child widget to disappear

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

While nesting two `Transform` widgets, child widget (I.E. a picture) is disappearing in some cases.

It happens with `Animation` and `AnimatedBuilder` as well.

Conditions for reproducing:

- Wide screen resolution only.
- Flutter Web with HTML web renderer only (Not Android nor Flutter Web with `CanvasKit`)
- Flutter 2.10.2

Minimal reproduce:

1. Create new folder `flutter_web_bug`
2. Open terminal inside that folder and execute `flutter create .`
3. Replace `./lib/main.dart` contents with the following code
4. Open terminal and execute `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`

   ```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:math';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter web bug',
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter web bug'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      double angle = 0.0;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), (timer) {
          setState(() {
            angle += 0.01;
          });
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                    ..rotateY(pi * angle),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                          color: const Color(0xffaaffff),
                          child: Transform(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(pi),
                              child: Image.network('https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/dash/dash-fainting.gif'))))),
            ));
      }
    }
   ```

Demonstration:

[image: HTML web renderer bug]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with `Image.network()` where the image is rebuilding. I tested using the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) library and was able to get the image to stay rendered while animating. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It doesn't seem to have any connection to child's type. It happens with `Text` widget too. Even if there is a connection, why is it happening and how to get through this issue?

Comment: Hmmmm...not really sure to be honest. I'll try to dive deeper and let you know if I can pinpoint it!